# What type of squash is growing out of my compost pile?

Tags: identification, compost, vines, squash

I didn't turn my compost pile this spring, and had an unexpected surprise that's been growing for the last few weeks. Can anyone identify what it is? I'm almost 100% sure it's some type of squash, but I don't know enough to tell what variety it is. From what I can remember, I've put waste from zucchini, acorn, spaghetti, and butternut squashes in the compost pile.

[image]  [image] [image]

[image]

There's also another smaller plant which looks very similar, but the leaves are a different shape.

[image]

Full size pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEzdT.jpg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on what I've seen, and confirmed a bit by a couple of quick searches, the photos on top with the deeply indented leaves look like melon.

The one on the bottom looks like a cucumber, though maybe it could be a squash.

As a side note, zucchini, acorn, and spaghetti squashes are all *C. pepo* and could have crossed last year. If you have volunteers from any crosses and let them mature, you may end up with odd-looking fruit.

For what it's worth, last year I planted a half dozen hills of pumpkin & winter squash; they gave me maybe three semi-decent fruits. I didn't pull the volunteers that popped up out of the compost pile and they gave me at least 20 gorgeous pumpkins.

Comment: The fruit won't be mutants, but they may not be recognizable... But they could still be tasty.

Comment: Yeah, we've had pumpkini (pumpkin/zucchini) growing in our compost pile.

Comment: Well, unfortunately we'll never know if your identification was correct. Something (most likely rabbits) got to both plants and chewed/gnawed them to death. Good thing I have my actual garden fenced!